# Reading/writing in Loop with Memory Pre-Allocation in R

Tags: r, for-loop, memory-management

I have a working loop to read the text files (unknown names) from different folders (known location) and update those text files columns and saving again with same name in same folder

```
folders <- c(1,2,3)

for(i in seq_along(folders)){
        dt <- df[(df$id ==folders[i]),]
        dt$id <- NULL
        loc <- paste0("data/", folders[i])
        setwd(loc)
        file.names <- list.files(pattern = "*.txt$", all.files = FALSE,
                                 full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
                                 ignore.case = FALSE)


    for(j in seq_along(file.names)){
      text <- read.csv(file.names[j], header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)

      text2 <- merge(text, dt, by.x = "matched", by.y = "matched", all.x = T)
      write.table(text2, file.names[j], sep = ",", na="",
                  row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE, col.names = F)
      rm(text,text2)
      print(j)
    }
}
```

There are two problems i'm facing, 
first one its very slow, 
second one it uses too much ram/memory. 
Tried to do myself but don't know much about R. It is possible to increase the speed by creating some functions and "if simply initialize a vector (with NAs, zeros or any other value) with the total length and then run the loop, we can drastically increase the speed of our algorithm". I wish I could do something like that myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Addressing speed

I would recommend some print statements throughout your loops and see where time is being consumed.

#### Addressing memory (and speed)

You're using base R functions. Try using `dplyr::left_join()` instead of `merge` (`dplyr` tends to run `c++` under the hood, and is therefore up to ~100 times faster than equivalent functions in base R). You could also try some [`data.table` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146967/efficient-alternatives-to-merge-for-larger-data-frames-r)

`rm()` removes the objects, but doesn't actually free up the memory. Calling `gc()` *after* `rm()` will free up most of the memory that the now removed objects occupied. So try placing `gc()` after calling `rm()`.

#### Regarding vector preallocation

Vector preallocation helps because it reduces the need for R to make copies of vectors when combining them. That doesn't appear to be a problem here (as your code doesn't combine vectors).

Comment: tried gc() after rm() its taking more time as it pauses to clear up after every text file, i think i should try to find some other way

Comment: @Janjua use judgement as to how often to `gc()`. How about every 20th iteration. You can use some code like `for(i in 1:100) if(i %% 20 == 0) { print(paste("Iteration", i)) }`