# a faster implementation of merge.data.frame() in R

Tags: performance, r, dataframe

Let's say `a` and `b` are two data frames. The goal is to write a function
`f(a,b)` that produces a merged data frame, in the same way as merge
`merge(a,b,all=TRUE)` would do, that is filling missing variables in `a` or `b` with NAs. (The problem is `merge()` appears to be very slow.)

This can be done as follows (pseudo-code):

```
for each variable `var` found in either `a` or `b`, do:
    unlist(list(a.srcvar, b.srcvar), recursive=FALSE, use.names=FALSE)

where:
x.srcvar is x$var if x$var exists, or else
            rep(NA, nrow(x)) if y$var !is.factor, or else
            as.factor(rep(NA, nrow(x)))
```

and then wrap everything in a data frame.

Here's a "naive" implementation:

```
merge.datasets1 <- function(a, b) {
  a.fill <- rep(NA, nrow(a))
  b.fill <- rep(NA, nrow(b))
  a.fill.factor <- as.factor(a.fill)
  b.fill.factor <- as.factor(b.fill)
  out <- list()
  for (v in union(names(a), names(b))) {
    if (!v %in% names(a)) {
      b.srcvar <- b[[v]]
      if (is.factor(b.srcvar))
        a.srcvar <- a.fill.factor
      else
        a.srcvar <- a.fill
    } else {
      a.srcvar <- a[[v]]
      if (v %in% names(b))
        b.srcvar <- b[[v]]
      else if (is.factor(a.srcvar))
        b.srcvar <- b.fill.factor
      else
        b.srcvar <- b.fill
    }
    out[[v]] <- unlist(list(a.srcvar, b.srcvar),
                       recursive=FALSE, use.names=FALSE)
  }
  data.frame(out)
}
```

Here's a different implementation that uses "vectorized" functions:

```
merge.datasets2 <- function(a, b) {
  srcvar <- within(list(var=union(names(a), names(b))), {
    a.exists <- var %in% names(a)
    b.exists <- var %in% names(b)
    a.isfactor <- unlist(lapply(var, function(v) is.factor(a[[v]])))
    b.isfactor <- unlist(lapply(var, function(v) is.factor(b[[v]])))
    a <- ifelse(a.exists, var, ifelse(b.isfactor, 'fill.factor', 'fill'))
    b <- ifelse(b.exists, var, ifelse(a.isfactor, 'fill.factor', 'fill'))
  })
  a <- within(a, {
    fill <- NA
    fill.factor <- factor(fill)
  })
  b <- within(b, {
    fill <- NA
    fill.factor <- factor(fill)
  })
  out <- mapply(function(x,y) unlist(list(a[[x]], b[[y]]),
                                     recursive=FALSE, use.names=FALSE),
                srcvar$a, srcvar$b, SIMPLIFY=FALSE, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
  out <- data.frame(out)
  names(out) <- srcvar$var
  out
}
```

Now we can test:

```
sample.datasets <- lapply(1:50, function(i) iris[,sample(names(iris), 4)])

system.time(invisible(Reduce(merge.datasets1, sample.datasets)))
>>   user  system elapsed 
>>  0.192   0.000   0.190 
system.time(invisible(Reduce(merge.datasets2, sample.datasets)))
>>   user  system elapsed 
>>  2.292   0.000   2.293
```

So, the naive version is orders of magnitude faster than the other. How can
this be? I always thought that `for` loops are slow, and that one should
rather use `lapply` and friends and steer clear of loops in R. I would welcome any idea on how to improve my function in terms of speed.

Comment: Use `data.table`.

Comment: For loops are not inherently slow, IFF you use them sensible, in particular if you pre-allocate memory, don't expand the object while in the loop, etc.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich `data.table` doesn't work because its `merge` method doesn't include non-common variables in the resulting data.table.

Comment: Have you looked at this:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322219/whats-the-fastest-way-to-merge-join-data-frames-in-r

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that there's a way to do what you want with `data.table`.

Comment: What would be wrong with `merge(DT, DF, by = intersect(names(DT), names(DF)), all = TRUE)`

Comment: @mnel it's wrong because i don't want intersect() but union(). try this with union() and it fails.

Comment: What are you actually merging by? Only by factor columns?

Comment: This explains the plyr method. I didn't benchmark this specific code but it's typically one of the faster options.  In plyr it's a `full join`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9652931/168689

Comment: There's also the sqldf option.  It uses the sqlite engine so it's fast and if you know sql the syntax is easy.  In sqldf it's a `outer join`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4483202/168689

Comment: @mnel I'm stacking data.frames and filling the missing columns in either data.frame with NAs.

Comment: @ErnestA `rbind.fill.matrix(...)` and `cbind.fill.matrix(...)` in the `plyr` package will fill NA's in the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, you are not doing trying to replicate `merge(a,b, all = TRUE)` at all, as you are not trying to merge on any of the columns. Instead you are simply stacking the data, filling with `NA` where a column does not exist.

```
 # note  that this is not what you want/
dim(merge(sample.datasets[[1]], sample.datasets[[2]], all = T))
 [1] 314   5
```

The reason `merge(a,b, all = TRUE)` will be slow is that it defaults to merging by the intersection of the names. If you convert to `data.tables` then the `merge.data.table` method is lightning fast, but with your test data, it would be creating an exponentially increasing dataset on each sucessive merge (not 7500 by 5 as you want your results to be)

An easy solution is to use `rbind.fill` from the `plyr` package.

```
library(plyr)
system.time({.x <- Reduce(rbind.fill, sample.datasets)})
## user  system elapsed 
## 0.16    0.00    0.15 
# which is almost identical to
system.time(.old <- Reduce(merge.datasets1, sample.datasets))
##   user  system elapsed 
##   0.14    0.00    0.14
```

## EDIT 2-11-2012

On  further consideration it is really useful to note that you can pass a list of `data.frames` to `rbind.fill` so

```
 system.time(super_fast <- rbind.fill(sample.datasets))
 ##  user  system elapsed 
 ##  0.02    0.00    0.02 

identical(super_fast, .old)
[1] TRUE
```

The majority of time spent in the overheads for `Reduce`, which `rbind.fill` does not require.