# R: creating a new column in a data.frame based on values out of a second data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two (example) data.frames (df1, df2)

```
#df1
L <- LETTERS[1:4]
b <- sample(L, 20, replace = TRUE)
df1 <- data.frame(stuff1 = 1, stuff2 = 1:10, b = b, c= NA, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#df2
a <- c(10,20,30,40)
df2 <- data.frame(xx = L, yy = a, stringsAsFactors=FALSE )
```

i want to have a new column, let's say `c`, in `df1` based on the values out of `df2`. One example: `A` has the corresponding value of 10 (see `df2`) so for every A in column `b` of `df1` should be 10 written down in the (new) line `c`. And this for every row of `xx` in `df2`, so in this case A,B,C and D. My code is not really working and is based only for a single value, here `A`:

```
##copy column b now it is c
df1["c"] <- df1$b


# which value has A in df2?
zz <- df2[df2$xx == "A",]
xy <- zz$yy


# fill in the new value in c (this is not working)
df1[df1$c == "A", ] <- xy
```

i hope it is clear what i want to say... oh and i have some big data this is only an example to try out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to do a merge/join. First, let's drop the empty `c` in `df1` and change the column names a bit:

```
 df1 <- df1[, !names(df1) %in% "c"]
 colnames(df2) <- c("b", "c")
```

With just `base` R, we can use `merge`:

```
 df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by="b", type="left")
 head(df3)

  b stuff1 stuff2  c
1 A      1      1 10
2 A      1      2 10
3 A      1      3 10
4 A      1      3 10
5 A      1     10 10
6 A      1      7 10
```

The package `plyr` has an alternative that might be faster and will preserve column order:

```
library(plyr)
df4 <- join(df1, df2, by="b", type="left")
head(df4)

  stuff1 stuff2 b  c
1      1      1 A 10
2      1      2 A 10
3      1      3 A 10
4      1      4 B 20
5      1      5 B 20
6      1      6 B 20
```

I don't know how well that will scale with the size of your data, but if it doesn't, you could try `data.table` or `sqldf`. I haven't used these two so I can't speak much to them, but here's a [comparison of their speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322219/whats-the-fastest-way-to-merge-join-data-frames-in-r) that might be a good starting point.

Comment: hey, thanks. it works fine with my data, i am using `join`and it is fast enough for me. Please can you say a little bit for the first row of your code?

Comment: It's just to drop the `c` column: `%in%` does set comparison, e.g. try `c(1, 2, 3) %in% 1`. More here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-columns-r-data-frame