# Simultaneously subsetting and operating on a specific column of a data frame

Tags: r, subset

Let's say I have data.frame `df`

```
df<-data.frame(a=1:5,b=101:105,c=201:205)
```

Can I call a subset of this data while simultaneously performing some kind of modification (e.g., arithmetic) to one of the columns (or rows) on the fly?

For example, if I want to return the first and second column of `df` but return the log of column 1 values. Is there some notation to modify `df[,1:2]` to produce the following all on the fly?:

```
            a   b
>1  0.0000000 101
>2  0.6931472 102
>3  1.0986123 103
>4  1.3862944 104
>5  1.6094379 105
```

Comment: the `dplyr` package is good for this sort of thing.

Comment: @JohnPaul the data.table package might also be a goog alternative, [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31885840/2204410) for an implementation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a good example for `within()`

```
within(df[1:2], a <- log(a))
#           a   b
# 1 0.0000000 101
# 2 0.6931472 102
# 3 1.0986123 103
# 4 1.3862944 104
# 5 1.6094379 105
```

Or if you prefer not to have `<-` in the call, you can use brackets

```
within(df[1:2], { a = log(a) })
```

Answer (score 6):

An approach with `data.table` could be as follows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(a=log(a),b)]
```

A test on large datasets:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- CJ(a = seq(1, 1e3, by=1), b = sample(1e2L), c = sample(1e2L))
df1 <- copy(dt1)
setDF(df1)
```

The benchmark:

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(replications = 10, order = "elapsed", columns = c("test", "elapsed", "relative"),
          dt = dt1[, .(a=log(a),b)],
          dplyr = transmute(df1, a = log(a), b = b),
          transform = transform(df1, a = log(a), b = b),
          within = within(df1, a <- log(a))[,1:2],
          twosteps = {df1<-df1[,1:2];df1[,1]<-log(df1[,1])})

       test elapsed relative
5  twosteps   0.249    1.000
4    within   0.251    1.008
3 transform   0.251    1.008
2     dplyr   0.300    1.205
1        dt   0.462    1.855
```

To my surprise, the `data.table` approach is the slowest one. While in most other cases (e.g.: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876335/merge-2-dataframes-by-matching-dates), [two](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Benchmarks-%3A-Grouping)) it is the faster approach.

Comment: `with(df1, data.frame(a = log(a), b = b))` is always fastest for me, I guess it's pretty similar to the two step though, but it actually returns a df

Comment: @DavidArenburg Not sure what I was thinking. I used that in the benchmark, but apperently not in the first part :-(. Changed now.

Answer (score 4):

Or the `dplyr` version:

```
library(dplyr)
transmute(df, a = log(a), b = b)
          a   b
1 0.0000000 101
2 0.6931472 102
3 1.0986123 103
4 1.3862944 104
5 1.6094379 105
```

In `dplyr`, `transmute()` will return only the variables named in the call to it. Here, we've only actually transformed one of the two variables, but we've included the second one in the result by creating a copy of it. In contrast to `transmute()`, `mutate()` will return the entirety of the original data frame, along with the variables created. If you give the new variables the same names as existing ones, `mutate()` will overwrite those.

One nice thing about the `dplyr` version is that it's easy to mix transformations and to give the results nice names, like this:

```
> transmute(df, a.log = log(a), b.sqrt = sqrt(b))
      a.log   b.sqrt
1 0.0000000 10.04988
2 0.6931472 10.09950
3 1.0986123 10.14889
4 1.3862944 10.19804
5 1.6094379 10.24695
```

Answer (score 3):

```
`[`(transform(df, a = log(a)),1:2)      
#          a   b
#1 0.0000000 101
#2 0.6931472 102
#3 1.0986123 103
#4 1.3862944 104
#5 1.6094379 105
```

You can call a subset while carrying out a function. But it's more sleight-of-hand then simultaneous operation. But the dplyr and other approaches will essentially mask the same behavior. If it is space and code golfing that you are trying to accomplish, this should help. I like the look of Mr.Flick's suggestion but this is a bit faster (bit).

Comment: What does the "`[`" do??

Comment: Why not just `transform(df, a = log(a))[1:2]`?

Comment: It looks cleaner, but the original is an edge faster

Comment: @PierreLafortune putting it in my million row benchmark below (the edit to jeremycg's answer), there's no difference.

Comment: @Gregor I agree, I did the test on 100k. Speed differences are almost exact at those magnitudes. I think there is a 4 or 5 micro-second difference. I think this whole thing is just Friday fun though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not convinced any of these are faster than the two step method, just doing it with less keystrokes. Here are some benchmarks:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(dplyr = {df<-data.frame(a=1:5,b=101:105,c=201:205);df<-transmute(df, a = log(a), b = b)},
               transform = {df<-data.frame(a=1:5,b=101:105,c=201:205);df<-transform(df, a = log(a))},
               within = {df<-data.frame(a=1:5,b=101:105,c=201:205);df<-within(df[1:2], a <- log(a))},
               twosteps = {df<-data.frame(a=1:5,b=101:105,c=201:205);df<-df[,1:2];df[,1]<-log(df[,1])})

Unit: microseconds
      expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
     dplyr 1374.710 1438.453 1657.3807 1534.0680 1658.2910  5231.572   100
 transform  489.597  508.413  764.6921  524.9240  569.4680 18127.718   100
    within  493.436  518.396  593.6254  534.9085  585.7880  1554.420   100
  twosteps  421.245  438.909  501.6850  450.6210  491.5165  2101.231   100
```

To demonstrate Gregor's comment below, first with 5 rows but putting the object creation outside of the benchmarking:

```
n = 5
df = data.frame(a = runif(n), b = rnorm(n), c = 1:n)

microbenchmark(dplyr = {df2 <- transmute(df, a = log(a), b = b)},
               subset = {df2 <- `[`(transform(df, a = log(a)),1:2)},
               within = {df2 <- within(df[1:2], a <- log(a))},
               twosteps = {df2 <- df[,1:2]; df2[,1]<-log(df2[,1])})
# twosteps looks much better!
```

But if you increase the number of rows to be big enough where you might care about the speed differences:

```
n = 1e6
df = data.frame(a = runif(n), b = rnorm(n), c = 1:n)

microbenchmark(dplyr = {df2 <- transmute(df, a = log(a), b = b)},
               subset = {df2 <- `[`(transform(df, a = log(a)),1:2)},
               within = {df2 <- within(df[1:2], a <- log(a))},
               twosteps = {df2 <- df[,1:2]; df2[,1]<-log(df2[,1])})
```

The differences go away.

Comment: Good to know!! My original question was not concerned with processing speed, though. Rather, I was more interested in reducing the lines of code and not having to define or update another object. All answers thus far accomplish that well. From your answer, though, I can see `within` is probably the way to go when using this approach. Thanks!

Comment: With such a small data frame (5 rows), a fairly large percentage of the time will be spent just in creating the data frame objects. It would be a better benchmark if you created the data beforehand---and then you'll see that with such a small dataframe the `twosteps` method is substantially faster, a factor of 2 to 10 (in the slow case of dplyr) times faster. *However*, on such a tiny example the difference is microseconds so it doesn't matter. If you up the size to a million row data frame the differences mostly go away.