# How can I add a column from one dataframe to another with certain conditions?

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes and I am using R:

| Van | Route | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| U31 | 23452 | 8:00 |
| U72 | 13422 | 7:00 |
| U98 | 53622 | 8:00 |
| U24 | 16622 | 8:00 |
| U75 | 76422 | 6:00 |
| U45 | 98422 | 8:00 |
| U27 | 46422 | 9:00 |

| Van | Seats |
| --- | --- |
| U27 | 20 |
| U72 | 22 |
| U24 | 13 |
| U98 | 16 |
| U75 | 22 |
| U45 | 12 |
| U31 | 22 |

the problem here is that both data frames are ordered differently and I would like to add the column of "Seats" to my first DF.

This is the result I want:

| Van | Route | Time | Seats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U31 | 23452 | 8:00 | 22 |
| U72 | 13422 | 7:00 | 22 |
| U98 | 53622 | 8:00 | 16 |
| U24 | 16622 | 8:00 | 13 |
| U75 | 76422 | 6:00 | 22 |
| U45 | 98422 | 8:00 | 12 |
| U27 | 46422 | 9:00 | 20 |

So I would like to basically add this column with the condition that DF1$Vans = DF2$Vans!!!

Thanks in advance :))

Comment: If the solutions helped please mark one as answer so it is marked as solved. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Perform a simple merge:

```
newdf = merge(df1, df2, by="Van")
```

If `df2` includes more columns, subset `df2` to the desired column and column used to merge:

```
newdf = merge(df1, df2[,c("Van","Seats")], by="Van")
```

Comment: How do I specify that I want to add the "Seats" column? Actually the second DF has more columns.. I just want the "Seats" column. Thanks and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @MateoGuajardo I edited my answer to answer your question

Answer (score 1):

```
# set as data.table
lapply(list(df1, df2), \(i) setDT(i))

# join
df2[df1
    , on=.(Vans)
    , mget(c("i.Van", "x.Seats"))
    ]
# assuming df1 has columns "Van", Route", "Time" as OP has not specified
```

Comment: How do I specify that I want to add the "Seats" column? Actually the second DF has more columns.. I just want the "Seats" column. Thanks and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: edited to fetch back only columns `Van` and `Seats`. Edit the `mget` argument as needed.
Also try to adhere to [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) guide as it will help us help you :)

Comment: @larenite
Thank you for your submission to improve the answer. Your suggestion of `merge` was not my top choice because of speed for which `data.table` is known for. [Please see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322219/whats-the-fastest-way-to-merge-join-data-frames-in-r)
Furthermore, you have provided the `merge` solution. Still, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2[,c("Van","Seats")], by = "Van")
```

`df2[,c("Van","Seats")]` subsets `df2` on two columns: `Van`, which is the column `df1` and `df2`have in common and based on which the join can be performed, as well as `Seats`,  the column you want to add to `df1`

Comment: How do I specify that I want to add the "Seats" column? Actually the second DF has more columns.. I just want the "Seats" column. Thanks and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Please see edited answer. .