# How to compute weighted means of a vector within factor levels?

Tags: r

I am able to successfully get a simple mean of a given vector within factor levels, but in attempting to take it to the next step of weighting the observations, I can't get it to work.  This works:

```
> tapply(exp.f,part.f.p.d,mean)
    1         2         3         4         5         6         7        8             9        10 
0.8535996 1.1256058 0.6968142 1.4346451 0.8136110 1.2006801 1.6112160 1.9168835     1.5135006 3.0312460
```

But this doesn't:

```
> tapply(exp.f,part.f.p.d,weighted.mean,b.pct)
Error in weighted.mean.default(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  'x' and 'w' must have the same length
>
```

In the code below, I am trying to find the weighted mean of exp.f, within levels of the factor part.f.p.d, weighted by the observations within b.pct that are in each level.

```
b.exp <- tapply(exp.f,part.f.p.d,weighted.mean,b.pct)

Error in weighted.mean.default(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  'x' and 'w' must have the same length
```

I am thinking I must be supplying the incorrect syntax, as all 3 of these vectors are the same length:

```
> length(b.pct)
[1] 978
> length(exp.f)
[1] 978
> length(part.f.p.d)
[1] 978
```

What is the correct way to do this?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi jonw-  exp.f is a numeric vector of stock expected returns,part.f.p.d is a factor with 10 levels, and b.pct are percentages for each stock in an index (the top 1000 stocks)

Comment: See answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685492/r-speeding-up-group-by-operations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Now* I do it like this (thanks to Gavin):

```
sapply(split(Data,Data$part.f.p.d), function(x) weighted.mean(x$exp.f,x$b.pct)))
```

Others likely use `ddply` from the plyr package:

```
ddply(Data, "part.f.p.d", function(x) weighted.mean(x$exp.f, x$b.pct))
```

Comment: @Prasad: I knew the obligatory plyr solution would get some up-votes. ;-)

Comment: thank you - I can see that I need to invest some time learning what plyr is all about. cheers.

Comment: @Joshua the `do.call` is a bit of extra overkill here. `sapply(split(Data, Data$part.f.p.d), function(x) weighted.mean(x$exp.f,x$b.pct))` would be sufficient to return a vector of weighted means. The simplicity of your `split` approach (+1) is hidden by the `rbind`+`do.call` wrapping.

Comment: Why the plyr love-in? ;-) I agree it is a very nice package, but such simple problems as that posed in the Q can be handled very nicely via basic R functionality without needing to learn a new package.

Comment: @Gavin: The `do.call(rbind, ...)` stuff is just habit that works on more general problems.  You're right that `sapply` is much nicer in this case.

Comment: @Gavin the idea behind plyr is that by being more consistent you don't need to remember the bewildering array of aggregation functions in base r, let alone their inconsistent parameters.

Comment: @hadley I guess having grown up in a world before plyr the various base R options and arguments are burned into my synapses - probably as a result of having to remember all the various functions and inconsistent arguments :-)

Answer (score 2):

I've recreated the error with some dummy data. I'm assuming that `part.f.p.d` is some kind of factor that you're using to separate the other vectors.

```
b.pct <- sample(1:100, 10) / 100
exp.f <- sample(1:1000, 10)
part.f.p.d <- factor(rep(letters[1:5], 2))

tapply(exp.f, part.f.p.d, mean) # this works
tapply(exp.f, part.f.p.d, weighted.mean, w = b.pct) # this doesn't
```

A call to `traceback()` helps to uncover the problem. The reason the second doesn't work is because the `INDEX` argument (ie `part.f.p.d`) that you passed to `tapply()` is used to split the `X` argument (ie `exp.f`) into smaller vectors. Each of these splits is applied to `weighted.mean()` together with the `w` argument (ie `b.pct`), which was not split.

EDIT: This should do what you want.

```
sapply(levels(part.f.p.d), 
       function(whichpart) weighted.mean(x = exp.f[part.f.p.d == whichpart], 
                                         w = b.pct[part.f.p.d == whichpart]))
```

Comment: thank you - is there some tweak that would make this work to calculate a weighted.mean that you know of?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `tapply` does not "split" the extra arguments supplied (through its `...` arguments) to the function, as it does for the main argument `X`. See the 'Note' on the help page for `tapply` (`?tapply`).

> Optional arguments to FUN supplied by
>   the ... argument are not divided into
>   cells. It is therefore inappropriate
>   for FUN to expect additional arguments
>   with the same length as X.

Here is a hacky solution.

```
exp.f <- rnorm(10)
part.f.p.d <- factor(sample(1:5, size = 10, replace = T))
b.pct <- rnorm(10)
a <- split(exp.f, part.f.p.d)
b <- split(b.pct, part.f.p.d)
lapply(seq_along(a), function(i){
  weighted.mean(a[[i]], b[[i]])
})
```