# Elegant way to solve ddply task with aggregate (hoping for better performance)

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr

I would like to aggregate a `data.frame` by an identifier variable called `ensg`. The data frame looks like this:

```
  chromosome probeset               ensg symbol    XXA_00    XXA_36    XXB_00
1          X  4938842 ENSMUSG00000000003   Pbsn  4.796123  4.737717  5.326664
```

I want to compute the mean for each numeric column over rows with same `ensg` value. The problem here is that I would like to leave the other identity variables chromosome and symbol untouched as they are also the same for same `ensg`.

In the end I would like to have a `data.frame` with identity columns `chromosome`, `ensg`, `symbol` and mean of numeric columns over rows with same identifier. I implemented this in `ddply`, but it is very slow when compared to `aggregate`:

```
spec.mean <- function(eset.piece)
  {
    cbind(eset.piece[1,-numeric.columns],t(colMeans(eset.piece[,numeric.columns])))
  }
t
mean.eset <- ddply(eset.consensus.grand,.(ensg),spec.mean,.progress="tk")
```

My first aggregate implementation looks like this,

```
mean.eset=aggregate(eset[,numeric.columns], by=list(eset$ensg), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE);
```

and is much faster. But the problem with `aggregate` is that I have to reattach the describing variables. I have not figured out how to use my custom function with `aggregate` since `aggregate` does not pass data frames but only vectors.

Is there an elegant way to do this with `aggregate`? Or is there some faster way to do it with `ddply`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First let's define a toy example:

```
df <- data.frame(chromosome = gl(3,  10,  labels = c('A',  'B',  'C')),
             probeset = gl(3,  10,  labels = c('X',  'Y',  'Z')),
             ensg =  gl(3,  10,  labels = c('E1',  'E2',  'E3')),
             symbol = gl(3,  10,  labels = c('S1',  'S2',  'S3')),
             XXA_00 = rnorm(30),
             XXA_36 = rnorm(30),
             XXB_00 = rnorm(30))
```

And then we use `aggregate` with the formula interface:

```
df1 <- aggregate(cbind(XXA_00, XXA_36, XXB_00) ~ ensg + chromosome + symbol,  
    data = df,  FUN = mean)

> df1
  ensg chromosome symbol      XXA_00      XXA_36      XXB_00
1   E1          A     S1 -0.02533499 -0.06150447 -0.01234508
2   E2          B     S2 -0.25165987  0.02494902 -0.01116426
3   E3          C     S3  0.09454154 -0.48468517 -0.25644569
```

Comment: Thanks for this beautiful solution! It is also lightning fast compared to ddply. I didn't know about the power of the formula interface! I have been using R for a couple of months now, but it keeps surprising me (in a good way).

Embarrasingly, I still lack the reputation for voting your solution up...

Comment: @Johannes: FWIW, the formula interface is slower than the others.

Comment: I have now adapted the solution posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3685919/1093951) by hadley. It relies on converting the data to a matrix before applying the mean leading to a huge speed increase. With my data set of dimension 10^5 x 43 the speed increases by a factor of 25!

Answer (score 8):

If speed is a primary concern, you should take a look at the `data.table` package. When the number of rows or grouping columns is large, `data.table` really seems to shine. The wiki for the package is [here](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=packages:cran:data.table) and has several links to other good introductory documents.

Here's how you'd do this aggregation with `data.table()`

```
library(data.table)
#Turn the data.frame above into a data.table
dt <- data.table(df)
#Aggregation

  dt[, list(XXA_00 = .Internal(mean(XXA_00)),
          XXA_36 = .Internal(mean(XXA_36)),
          XXB_00 = .Internal(mean(XXB_00))),
    by = c("ensg", "chromosome", "symbol")
   ]
```

Gives us

```
     ensg chromosome symbol      XXA_00      XXA_36    XXB_00
[1,]   E1          A     S1  0.18026869  0.13118997 0.6558433
[2,]   E2          B     S2 -0.48830539  0.24235537 0.5971377
[3,]   E3          C     S3 -0.04786984 -0.03139901 0.5618208
```

The aggregate solution provided above seems to fare pretty well when working with the 30 row data.frame by comparing the output from the [rbenchmark](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/benchmark/index.html) package. However, when the data.frame contains 3e5 rows, `data.table()` pulls away as a clear winner. Here's the output:

```
 benchmark(fag(), fdt(), replications = 10)
   test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self 
1 fag()           10   12.71 23.98113     12.40     0.31     
2 fdt()           10    0.53  1.00000      0.48     0.05
```

Comment: Not a fan of encouraging users to call functions via `.Internal` interactively and I doubt it makes that much of a difference in this case.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich - I've never been bitten by `.Internal` so can't really say one way or another. The wiki page for `data.table` shows a nearly 10x improvement in speed for `.Internal(mean())` over `mean()` in their test case. That's where I picked up that (possibly bad) habit. I'll update the test using standard `mean()` and see what actually happens though.

Comment: You could use `mean.default` instead of `mean` to avoid the method dispatch and that would save you a little time.  I don't mind showing `.Internal` as a _option_ as long as it's followed with a "here be dragons" warning.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich -- Using `mean.default` is a nice suggestion.  I just tried it out with the example on the wiki page (http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=packages:cran:data.table#don_t_use_mean_x_use_.internal_mean_x), and `mean.default()` buys a 4X speedup relative to `mean()`. (`.Internal(mean())` achieves an 8X speedup.)

Comment: This one could do with an edit. No need to worry about `.Internal` anymore, as @JoshuaUlrich was quite right about. As of a few versions ago `mean` now gets optimized automatically. Should it be an edit tacked on the end, or just change the answer and benchmark again? Not sure.